# Get position of rendered object as map tile coordinates

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

I'm using libgdx to render a map that is 32x32 tiles (with each tile being 32x32 pixels). I'm using the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer for this. Then, I'm rendering a simple texture onto the screen that can move around using up/down/right/left. What I want is to get the position of the texture in terms of the map tiles positions. For example, if the texture is on top of tile (0, 0) I want to know this. So far, I've tried using `camera.unproject(texcoordpositionVector)` to get these, but it hasn't been working consistently.

Edit: here's how the map renderer and camera are setup:

```
SCALE = 10;
w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

map = new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");
camera = new OrthographicCamera(SCALE * (w / h), SCALE);
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/32f);
```

Then, to render:

```
camera.update();
camera.apply(Gdx.graphics.getGL10());
renderer.setView(camera);
renderer.render();
```

Comment: How did you setup your camera(s) and/or the map renderer's view?  `camera.unproject` is the right place to start, but you may need to massage the result based on your unit scale.

Comment: @P.T. I edited my question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your texture is being drawn with the same camera as the map, then it should already be in tile space. If you are using a different camera, then you would need to project the position using that camera, then unproject it with the map camera.

Comment: What do you mean by "drawn with the same camera as the map"? Do you mean that I should set the projection matrix of the SpriteBatch object I'm using to render the texture to be `camera.projection`?

Comment: Yes... Normally, you'd use the same units for the map and the objects being drawn on the map. That means either configuring your objects to use the scale of the map, or setting up your map renderer to match the other objects. The [Super Koalio](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/superkoalio/SuperKoalio.java) example shows one approach to this.

Comment: Okay, I looked at that and am now using `renderer.getSpriteBatch()` for drawing the texture. The problem is though, that it draws the texture way too big every time.

Comment: You need to scale the texture to match the scale of the map. See lines 92-93 of the Super Koalio example.